# Cannot create constructor for angular component with a string as param

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple component:

```
export class PlaintextComponent implements OnInit {
  schema: PlaintextTagSchema;

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, prompt: string, maxRows: number, maxChars: number) {
    this.schema.prompt = prompt;
    this.schema.maxRows = maxRows;
    this.schema.maxChars = maxChars;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

When I try to compile my app using ng serve, I get the error:

```
component.ts:25:40 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'prompt' of class 'PlaintextComponent'.
Found string

25   constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, prompt: string, maxRows: number, maxChars: number) {
```

I've looked all over on the internet for this cryptic error and haven't found anything resembling a fix. It looks like a correct constructor to me, but I'm new to angular/TS and it's highly possible i'm missing something incredibly basic. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try type any and cast to string inside the constructor

Comment: How and where are you passing prompt, maxRows and maxChars  values to the PlaintextComponent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 - build --prod failed with error: Can't resolve all parameters for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465356/angular-7-build-prod-failed-with-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for)

Comment: Nilanka, this just changes the error to "found any"

Comment: bjdose, I cannot even create a plaintextcomponent yet, the definition doesn't compile

Comment: Aluan, I'm not sure how to implement that solution as the problem looks different than mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. Looks like Angular is trying to do some dependecies injection with the parameters in the constructor (like the ones you do with services), but in your case, this will lead to errors. Just declare your class properties out of the parameters of the constructor. Move your class properties out of the constructor like this:

```
export class PlaintextComponent implements OnInit {
  schema: PlaintextTagSchema;
  private _ngZone: NgZone;
  prompt: string;
  maxRows: number; 
  maxChars: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

You maybe have to find another way to initialize your Component, like input properties.

Please, let me know if it works! ;D

Comment: This helped me find the solution - I didn't really understand how constructors in angular worked, and turns out what I was trying to do generally wasn't acceptable

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the Constructor as following

```
  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone, @Inject(String) prompt: string, maxRows: number, maxChars: number)
```

dont forget

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer